# Problem deleting all sub-menu items correctly in CMFCMenuButton

Tags: visual-c++, menu, mfc, cmfcmenubutton

I am getting myself confused.

I have a menu:

```
IDR_MENU_POPUP_MANAGE_GROUPS MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "__MANAGE_GROUP__"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Add Group",                   ID_POPUP_ADD_GROUP
        POPUP "Edit Group"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "__EDIT__",                    ID_POPUP_EDIT_GROUP_BASE
        END
        POPUP "Delete Group"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "__DELETE__",                  ID_POPUP_DELETE_GROUP_BASE
        END
    END
END
```

This is used by a `CMFCMenuButton`. At runtime I dynamically delete the two submenus like this:

```
CMenu* pMenu = m_menuManageGroups.GetSubMenu(0);
CMenu* pSubMenu = nullptr;

pSubMenu = pMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
pMenu->RemoveMenu(ID_POPUP_EDIT_GROUP_BASE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

In the first instance that works and the Edit sub-menu is not there in my menu button.

But then I add some menu items to the sub menu:

```
for (auto& groupInfo : mapGroups)
{
    // first:  Group Name
    // second: Group Id
    const auto iMenuItemId = iMenuBase + groupInfo.second;

    pSubMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, iMenuItemId, groupInfo.first);

}
```

They get added and I see them in the sub menu of the button.

Now, if for some reason I run this code a second time it ends up adding the new menu items to the bottom of the existing sub menu in the menu button. Why? I thought `RemoveMenu` would delete all existing sub menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
const auto menuCount = pSubMenu->GetMenuItemCount();
for (int iMenuItem = 0; iMenuItem < menuCount; iMenuItem++)
{
    pSubMenu->DeleteMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION);
}
```

But I still don't understand why I had to do this because I thought:

```
pMenu->RemoveMenu(iMenuBase, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

... would get rid of all the sub-menu items in the flyout.

Comment: According to the docs: "If the menu item opens a drop-down menu or submenu, **RemoveMenu** does not destroy the menu or its handle, allowing the menu to be reused. "

Comment: @user20716902 But it still doesn't explain it. The first time round it did clear the menu contents out. So why did it all appear duplicated the second time? My workaround is sufficient but it is annoying.